# C++ - Enable instantiation of variadic templated struct without template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a `Tuple` struct defined with variadic templates as follows:

```
template<bool b> struct booltype {};

template<typename ...Types>
struct Tuple;

template<typename Type, typename... Types>
struct Tuple<Type, Types...> : public Tuple<Types...>
{
    template<typename T, typename B = booltype<true>>
    struct contains : std::false_type { };

    template<typename T>
    struct contains<T, booltype<std::is_same<T, Type>::value || Tuple<Types...>::template contains<T>::value>> : std::true_type { };

    // ...
};

// This does not allow for "Tuple t;" as expected
template<>
struct Tuple<>
{
    template<typename T>
    struct contains : std::false_type { };
};
```

Now, I want to be able to write

```
Tuple t;
```

to create an empty tuple instead of

```
Tuple<> t;
```

while specifying the internal `contains` struct as inheriting from `std::false_type`. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/16rY7b)

Comment: I don't think is possible before C++17. Starting from C++17, works as is, thanks to implicit template argument deduction.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. - You've compiled with C++20; the problem is before C++17 (no CTAD).

Comment: @max66 yes I did, because the current standard is C++20.